# UPDATE column where another column LIKE specific string

Tags: sql, rows

I tried to figure out how to do this, but no luck, so I am asking for help...

I have a table named products and I need to update in a column names refresh_time all rows that LIKE "-295" in another column named "ref"

I tried

```
UPDATE products SET refresh_time = "2014-10-26 08:33:29" WHERE products.ref LIKE "295-"
```

No luck..

any help is highly appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Like -295 or Like 295- ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wildcard in your LIKE pattern.  And use single quotes.

`LIKE '295-%'`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp